# Basic Hangman Game in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started learning python a week back and I am trying to focus on very basic projects. I am stuck in "The Hangman Game"

> https://www.codementor.io/@ilyaas97/6-python-projects-for-beginners-yn3va03fs
>   Hangman
>   This is probably the hardest one out of these 6 small
>   projects. This will be similar to guessing the number, except we are
>   guessing the word. The user needs to guess letters, Give the user no
>   more than 6 attempts for guessing wrong letter. This will mean you
>   will have to have a counter.

I have written this code till now:

```
import random

name = input("Please enter your name to play Hangman! ")

print("Welcome "+name+" !. Lets play Hangman.")

wrong_attempt = int(input("How many incorrect attempts do you want ? "))

f = open('words.csv',"r")

secret_word = f.readline()
#print(secret_word)
guesses = ''
while wrong_attempt > 0 :
    c = 0
    letter = input("\nGuess a word : ")
    for char in secret_word :
        if char == letter :
            print(char,end = '')
        else :
            print('*',end = '')
            c += 1
            if c == len(secret_word) :
                wrong_attempt -= 1
                print("Bad Luck. You have ",wrong_attempt," attempts left.")
                print("The secret word is ",secret_word)

if wrong_attempt == 0 :
    print("You LOSE.")
```

The output I am getting right now :

```
Please enter your name to play Hangman! ss Welcome ss !. Lets play Hangman. How many incorrect attempts do you want ? 2

Guess a word : c c******** Guess a word : o
*o******* Guess a word : m
**m****** Guess a word : z
*********Bad Luck. You have  1  attempts left.

Guess a word : d
*********Bad Luck. You have  0  attempts left. You LOSE. The secret word is  computer
```

Expected Output :

```
Please enter your name to play Hangman! ss Welcome ss !. Lets play Hangman. How many incorrect attempts do you want ? 2

Guess a word : c c******** Guess a word : o co******* Guess a word : m com****** Guess a word : z
*********Bad Luck. You have  1  attempts left.

Guess a word : d
*********Bad Luck. You have  0  attempts left. You LOSE. The secret word is  computer
```

Also I am new to stackoverflow when it comes to posting questions. Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: What is different in your output that you don't want?

Comment: In your code, you do not take in account the letters which have been rightly guessed so far, only the one guessed during this turn. I would advice you to create a string, initialized with `******` (with the right length), and that gets actualized along the guesses. That would also allow you to know if the player won the game or not. I would also suggest to rename your variable ``wrong_attempt` in `attempt_left`, its name is misleaading.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you meant:

Essentially what i did was create a list and populated the items with astriks and then at the char check i popped the n-th astriks and replaced it with the letter.

```
import random
import sys
name = input("Please enter your name to play Hangman! ")

print("Welcome "+name+" !. Lets play Hangman.")

wrong_attempt = int(input("How many incorrect attempts do you want ? "))

f = open('words.csv',"r")

secret_word = f.readline()
#print(secret_word)
guesses = ''
word = []
for i in secret_word.strip("\n"):
    word.append("*")
while wrong_attempt > 0 :
    word_str = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in word])

    #print(word_str)
    c = 0
    letter = input("\nGuess a word : ")
    for char in secret_word :
        if char == letter :
            word.pop(c)
            word.insert(c,char)
            c += 1
        else :
            c += 1
            if c == len(secret_word) :
                wrong_attempt -= 1
                print("Bad Luck. You have ",wrong_attempt," attempts left.")
                print("The secret word is ",secret_word)
    c=0

    word_str = ''.join([str(elem) for elem in word])
    print(word_str)
    if word_str == secret_word.strip("\n"):
        print("Yeee, you won")
        sys.exit()
if wrong_attempt == 0 :
    print("You LOSE.")
```

Answer (score -1):

The only difference I can tell is this line in the expected code:

Guess a word : c c******** Guess a word : o co******* Guess a word : m com****** Guess a word : z

while yours is :

Guess a word : c c******** Guess a word : o

*o******* Guess a word : m
**m****** Guess a word : z

so try making a tab \t at the end instead of \n in this line:

```
    letter = input("\nGuess a word : ")
```

Comment: if you would have read the code then you would have seen that every line is on a separate line. The issue in the code was that with every guess only the right letters from that try were visible.